# C string arrays

Tags: c, arrays, string

I just wrote a string splitting function:

```
typedef enum {
    strspl_allocation_error = 1
} strspl_error;


int strspl(const char *string, const char separator, char ***result) {

    const int stringLength = strlen(string);
    int lastSplit = 0;
    int numberOfComponents = 1;

    // Compute the number of components
    for (int i = 0; i <= stringLength; i++) {
        if (string[i] == separator)
            numberOfComponents++;
    }

    // Allocate space to hold pointers to each component
    *result = (char **) malloc(numberOfComponents * sizeof(char *));
    if (result == NULL)
        return strspl_allocation_error;

    numberOfComponents = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= stringLength; i++) {
        char c = string[i];
        if (c == separator || i == stringLength) {

            const int componentLength = i - lastSplit;

            // Allocate space to hold the component
            char *component = (char *) malloc(componentLength * sizeof(char));
            if (component == NULL)
                return strspl_allocation_error;

            // Copy the characters from the string into the component
            for (int j = 0; j < componentLength; j++)
                component[j] = string[lastSplit + j];
            component[componentLength] = '\0';

            // Put the component into the array
            *result[numberOfComponents] = component;

            lastSplit = i + 1;
            numberOfComponents++;
        }
    }

    return numberOfComponents;
}
```

Example:

```
char **result;
int r = strspl("aaaBcBddddeeBk", 'B', result);

for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    printf("component: %s\n", result[i]);
```

should output:

```
component: aaa
component: c
component: ddddee
component: k
```

But when I run it, it either crashes or returns garbage values. I don't understand where I'm making a mistake...

**Update:** here's a hopefully bugfree version:

```
int strspl(const char *string, const char separator, char ***results) {

    const char *separatorString = (char[]){separator, '\0'};
    int numberOfComponents = 0;
    int stringLength = strlen(string);

    int lastCharacterWasSeparator = 1;

    // Compute the number of components
    for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++) {
        if (string[i] != separator) {
            if (lastCharacterWasSeparator)
                numberOfComponents++;
            lastCharacterWasSeparator = 0;
        }
        else
            lastCharacterWasSeparator = 1;
    }

    // Allocate space to hold pointers to components
    *results = malloc(numberOfComponents * sizeof(**results));

    char *stringCopy = strdup(string); // A reference to the copy of the string to modify it and to free() it later.
    char *strptr = stringCopy; // This will be used to iterate through the string.
    int componentLength = 0;
    int component = 0;

    while (component < numberOfComponents) {

        // Move to the startpoint of the next component.
        while (componentLength == 0) {
            componentLength = strcspn(strptr, separatorString);

            // Break out the while loop if we found an actual component.
            if (componentLength != 0)
                break;

            // If we found two adjacent separators, we just "silently" move over them.
            strptr += componentLength + 1;
        }

        // Replace the terminating separator character with a NULL character.
        strptr[componentLength] = '\0';

        // Copy the new component into the array.
        (*results)[component++] = strdup(strptr);

        // Move the string pointer ahead so we can work on the next component.
        strptr += componentLength + 1;

        componentLength = 0;
    }

    // Free the copy of the string.
    free(stringCopy);

    return numberOfComponents;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry about that, all of what we suggested for you to do to fix it combined together and broke it again! From your original code, here are the adjustments you need:

1. The signature of the function needs to be `char ***result` instead of `char **result`.
2. The array allocation should be `*result = malloc(...)` instead of `result = malloc(...)`.
3. The component pointer was never being stored in the results array, a line reading: `(*result)[numberOfComponents] = component;` should be put after `component[componentLength] = '\0';` (the parenthesis are needed because the result parameter was changed to `char***`).
4. And finally, the call to the function should be something like this: `strspl(..., &result);` instead of `strspl(..., result);`

---

Pointers have always been one of the more difficult things to understand when working in C/C++... Let me see if I can explain this:

Let's say we have the caller with a stack like this:

```
Address     -  Data        -  Description
0x99887760  -  0xbaadbeef  -  caller-result variable (uninitialized garbage)
```

When the call is made like this: `strspl(..., result);`, the compiler copies the local pointer (`0xbaadbeef`) onto the stack of `strspl`:

```
Address     -  Data        -  Description
0x99887750  -  0xbaadbeef  -  strspl-result variable (copy of uninitialized garbage)
...
0x99887760  -  0xbaadbeef  -  caller-result variable (uninitialized garbage)
```

Now when we call `result = malloc(...)` and copy the result into the local strspl-result variable, we get:

```
Address     -  Data        -  Description
0x99887750  -  0x01000100  -  strspl-result variable (new array)
...
0x99887760  -  0xbaadbeef  -  caller-result variable (uninitialized garbage)
```

Obviously not updating the caller's result variable.

---

If instead we call with the address of the result variable: `strspl(..., &result);` we get this:

```
Address     -  Data        -  Description
0x99887750  -  0x99887760  -  strspl-result variable (pointer to the caller's result)
...
0x99887760  -  0xbaadbeef  -  caller-result variable (uninitialized garbage)
```

And then when we call `result = malloc(...)` we get this:

```
Address     -  Data        -  Description
0x99887750  -  0x01000100  -  strspl-result variable (new array)
...
0x99887760  -  0xbaadbeef  -  caller-result variable (uninitialized garbage)
```

Still not quite what we want, because the caller never gets the pointer to the array.

---

If instead we call `*result = malloc(...)` we get this:

```
Address     -  Data        -  Description
0x99887750  -  0x99887760  -  strspl-result variable (pointer to the caller's result)
...
0x99887760  -  0x01000100  -  caller-result variable (new array)
```

This way, when we return, we've overwritten the caller's garbage with our newly `malloc`'d array.

---

As you can see, the compiler is copying the address of the caller's variable onto the stack of the function being called. Because it's copied, the function cannot modify it unless the caller passes a pointer to it's variable (this is why it needed to be `char***` not `char**`).

I hope that clears things up without making it harder to understand! :-P

Comment: Done, still doesn't work. Or do I have to change anything else?

Comment: @Miquella looks like both our answers are on the same wavelength. +1 for going the extra mile in explanation.

Comment: @SiegeX Thanks! I've been itching to explain this to someone, so I figured I would (I just hope I didn't get anything wrong)

Comment: @Miquella I would edit your first case and make clear that you are calling strspl as `strspl(..., result);` i.e. *not* passing the address of result.

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all it is more correct to use `for(int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++)`, but it shouldn't be a big mistake in your case.
2. If you want to return an array of `char *` you should pass `char *** result` and assign
   `*result = (char**) malloc(...)`.
3. I do not see where you saving `component` pointer into your `result` array
4. I think it is better to use `strdup` or `strcpy` to copy strings

Comment: I would normally agree with you, but `for(int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++)` would mean additional code would have to be added after the loop to handle the final component. Having it be `for(int i = 0; i <= stringLength; i++)` with one extra check in the loop keeps you from writing extra code. And since it's already assumed to be null terminated, it doesn't cause a problem.

Comment: Good catch on point #2. I missed that the first time through.

Comment: Thanks,
1) did that with purpose to handle the final component
2) why?
3) updated the code, it still doesn't work
4) why?

Comment: @user###### 1) Yeah, I missed this idea, quite nice 2) Because to return a value through the parameter you should pass `type *` and your type is an array of strings (`char **`), so... 3) Doesn't work because of 2 4.a) memcpy could be faster 4.b) why to reinvent the wheel, it is usually better to use standard libraries - shorter code and works faster.

Answer (score 1):

1. You never assign the component
   strings into the `result` array
2. You have an off-by-one error when you `malloc` component because you don't account for the NUL
3. You need one more layer of indirection so you can alter the `char **result` when you pass it to your function
4. Don't cast `malloc()`'s return value in C.  See [**here**](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html) as to why

See [**THIS LINK**](http://ideone.com/8EUtJ) for a working implementation.

#### Update

Here is how I would implement `strspl()`

```
int strspl(const char *string, const int separator, char ***result)
{
    int len, n=1, i=0;
    char *strptr = *copy = strdup(string);

    while(*strptr++) {
        if (*strptr == separator){ n++; }
    }

    *result = malloc(n * sizeof(**result));

    //Reset Pointer to Beginning of string
    strptr = copy;

    while(len = strcspn(strptr, (char []){separator, '\0'})) {
        strptr[len] = '\0';
        (*result)[i++] = strdup(strptr);
        strptr += len + 1;
    }

    free(copy);
    return n;
}
```

#### Output

```
component: aaa
component: c
component: ddddee
component: k
```

Comment: @user see my updated answer with a link to a working implementation.

Comment: @user I updated my answer with what I think is a more efficient way of implementing your `strspl()` through the use of `strdup()`, `strcspn()` and poking holes in the string copy with `\0` to break them up.

Comment: Very good! Your solution is way way faster than mine. I also just found `strtok()`...

Comment: @user I had a typo in my last rev `strptr += len;` should be `strptr += len + 1;`  Anyway, I was under the impression you already knew about `strtok()` but didn't want to use it because it alters the string you pass in, hence your use of `const char *string`

Comment: @SiegeX well, I wasn't aware of `strtok()`'s existence, but you're right I can't directly use it. Maybe I'll implement a version of `strspl()` using `strtok()` to see how that performs.